# Escapar Caracteres Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

Tengo el siguiente atributo de un elemento con un valor JSON:

```
document.write('<div id="count-down-wrap-8090" class="ult-responsive ult_countdown-div ult_countdown-dateAndTime ult-wptz" data-labels="Años,Meses,Semanas,Días,Horas,Minutos,Segundos" data-labels2="Año,Mes,Semana,Día,Hora,Minuto,Segundo"  data-terminal-date="2019/09/20 08:00:00" data-countformat="DHMS" data-time-zone="0" data-time-now="'+fcha.getDate()+'/'+(fcha.getMonth()+1)+'/'+fcha.getFullYear()+' '+fcha.getHours()+':'+fcha.getMinutes()+':'+fcha.getSeconds()+'"  data-tick-col="#ffffff"   data-ultimate-target='#count-down-wrap-8090 .ult_countdown-amount'  data-responsive-json-new='{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}'  data-tick-p-col="#ffffff"  data-tick-style="font-weight:bold;"  data-tick-p-style=""  data-bg-color="" data-br-radius="" data-padd="0">'+fcha.getDate()+'/'+(fcha.getMonth()+1)+'/'+fcha.getFullYear()+' '+fcha.getHours()+':'+fcha.getMinutes()+':'+fcha.getSeconds()+'</div>');
```

Necesito escarpar sus comillas, de tal manera que pueda imprimir el elemento dentro de un `document.write(' ');` sin errores.

Yo lo hice ésta manera, pero me genera error en la conso:

```
document.write(' data-responsive-json-new="\'{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}\'" ');
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien... ¿qué es lo que quieres imprimir en sí?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, necesito imprimir ´data-responsive-json-new='{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}'´, pero me sale error por las comillas

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una simple respuesta **Template Literals.**

Como funcionan? Facil.. en vez de comillas simples ocupas algo asi: **`** son comillas simples pero en direccion contraria.

```js
const str = `data-responsive-json-new=\'{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}\'`

console.log(str)

document.write(str)
```

Comment: Olvide comentarte que con Template Literals puedes integrar variables sin concatenarlas, es super cool.. puedes leer mas por aca https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Si la salida que quieres es esta:

```
data-responsive-json-new='{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}'
```

Solamente tienes que escapar la comilla simple que hay antes de `{` y después de `}`, algo así:

```js
document.write('data-responsive-json-new=\'{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}\'');
```

Comment: Mil gracias Cedano por tu ayuda, en el editor no me sale error, pero en el navegador, los números salen: NaN

Comment: edité la pregunta de nuevo, échale un vistazo al elemento que necesito imprimir, me avisas si logras hacerlo porfa. Gracias.

Comment: @Candelo en ese caso pon todo dentro de *Template literals*  como sugiere la otra respuesta y así debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que no has escapado correctamente las comillas simples  (`eg: \'`) a partir del atributo `data-ultimate-target` en adelante.

#### Solución:

```
document.write('<div id="count-down-wrap-8090" class="ult-responsive ult_countdown-div ult_countdown-dateAndTime ult-wptz" data-labels="Años,Meses,Semanas,Días,Horas,Minutos,Segundos" data-labels2="Año,Mes,Semana,Día,Hora,Minuto,Segundo"  data-terminal-date="2019/09/20 08:00:00" data-countformat="DHMS" data-time-zone="0" data-time-now="'+fcha.getDate()+'/'+(fcha.getMonth()+1)+'/'+fcha.getFullYear()+' '+fcha.getHours()+':'+fcha.getMinutes()+':'+fcha.getSeconds()+'"  data-tick-col="#ffffff"   data-ultimate-target=\'#count-down-wrap-8090 .ult_countdown-amount\'  data-responsive-json-new=\'{"font-size":"desktop:60px;","line-height":""}\'  data-tick-p-col="#ffffff"  data-tick-style="font-weight:bold;"  data-tick-p-style=""  data-bg-color="" data-br-radius="" data-padd="0">'+fcha.getDate()+'/'+(fcha.getMonth()+1)+'/'+fcha.getFullYear()+' '+fcha.getHours()+':'+fcha.getMinutes()+':'+fcha.getSeconds()+'</div>');
```